# Why MongoDB connection string starts with mongodb:\\

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Why should I use the following syntax :

```
mongodb:\\localhost:27017
```

The localhost part I got but, why it does not works when I skip the mongodb:\ prefix ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why MongoDB connection string starts with mongodb:\

It doesn't, the slashes should be forward slashes:

```
mongodb://localhost:27017
```

Why? This is the format of the URI as agreed upon by the people who designed it.